# How do I get around Inconsistant accessibilty error in C #?

Tags: c#, methods, accessibility

How do I get around Inconsistant accessibilty error in C # ?

I need to pass a pointer to a node in a linked list to a method. 
When I do, I get a "Compiler Error CS0051"

Example
The following sample generates CS0051:

```
// CS0051.cs
public class A
{
  // Try making B public since F is public
  // B is implicitly private here
  class B
  {
  }

  public static void F(B b)  // CS0051
  {
  }

  public static void Main()
  {
  }
}
```

That is a simple example.  The actual program is a bit more complicated.  I am actually using a node in a linked list to pass to the method
LinkedListNode node

The method uses recursion because the node is mart of a huge linked list structure of linked lists that outputs an xml file.
Either I have to find a way to use recursion without using methods or I need to find a way to pass pointers nodes or actual nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a parameter defined as less than public on a public method.

In the example above, B should be public if you want to use it on the public F method.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could "get around" it is to make the method take a base type that is public as parameter instead of `B`. You can use `object` if there is no other base type. This is only useful if you have a public method that returns an internal type that later needs to be passed back to your code and it's generally not a good design. (Of course, the returning method would also have to return a public type.)

Otherwise you just have to make `B` a public type to make it work. What your code is saying right now is: *anyone can call this method, but only classes in this assembly can access the parameter type*. Of course, if they cannot access the parameter type then they cannot really call the method - that's what the C# compiler is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about a user of class A, they will be offered a public interface which includes `void F(B b)` . It's only logical that this user should be allowed to instantiate a B, otherwise the method F would be unusable.